# code obfuscation in android with proguard

Tags: android, eclipse

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, unComment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
```

proGuard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/ProGuard/ProGuard-android.txt:proGuard-project.txt

```
# Project target.
target=android-18
this is my project.properties file
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proGuard/proGuard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html
# Add any project specific keep options here:
# If your project uses WebView with JS, unComment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepClassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

this is my proguard-project.txt

I am enabling proguard like this when I try to build apk in release mode I am getting error code 1 in eclipse Juno. if I use same code in android studio I can able to build release apk . if I reverse engineer the apk which got from android studio I can read the entire code so how I can obfuscate the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to work with proguard you need to just enable proguard using gradil script .

open gradil file and enable minifiable true and try to sign your application